# Setting up disclosure triangles for Bootstrap 3 accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I am pretty frustrate that the Bootstrap 3 accordion control doesn't seem to have a built-n class toggle for open/close on the **heading** of the accordion.

I need to have an accordion with one css class on the header when its child is open, and another for it closed.  I'm close with the following code, but this doesn't cover the situation when a user closes and already opened pane without choosing a different pane -- it only works right if you keep choosing different panes.

The 3 things I need the headers to correctly show state:

- when a pane is set to be opened by default (add "in" class to html of that pane)
- when manually opened or closed, show right class
- when closed by clicking a different pane open

I so far have

```
    $(function() {
   $('h4.panel-title').each(function() {
        // check all headers to see if they have open children
        var isOpen = $(this).closest('.panel').find('.panel-collapse').hasClass('in');
        // and, if yes, set the class to "open"
        if (isOpen) {
            $(this).addClass('open');
        }
   });
   $('h4.panel-title').on('click', function(event) {
        // remove "open" class from all headers in this group
        $(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('h4.panel-title').removeClass('open');
        // then set the one clicked on to open
        $(this).addClass('open');
   });
```

With this html:

```
<div class="panel-group accordion-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseOne">
              Collapsible Group Item #1
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <div class="panel-body">
            text...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseTwo">
              Collapsible Group Item #2
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            text...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseThree">
              Collapsible Group Item #3
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            text...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

It didn't fully survive being pasted into a Fiddle, but here is is: http://jsfiddle.net/smlombardi/kW33s/

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(function() {    
   $('h4.panel-title').on('click', function(event) {
           // remove "open" class from all headers in this group
           $(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('h4.panel-title').removeClass('open');
           // remove "in" class from all collapse panel
           $(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('.collapse').removeClass("in");
           // then set the one clicked on to open
           $(this).addClass('open');
           $(this).parent().next(".collapse").addClass("in");
   });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kW33s/2/)

Comment: This is cleaner, but if there was more than one `.accordion-group` on the page it would close all of them, right?

Comment: Yeah, updated the code. Now it will target the current .accordion-group.

Answer (score 0):

I found this

[Bootstrap 3 accordion styling on open/closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592441/bootstrap-3-accordion-styling-on-open-closed)

I realized its better to hook into the BS3 accordion events than do the click event, since the issue I had was that the pane had the IN class when clicked even if the click was going to close it.