# change panel heading colour when bootstrap accordion is open

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-accordion

When i click on accordion tab its colour has to change indicating the current tab is open. I am using ng2 bootstrap accordion

```
  <accordion-group #group1 [ngClass]="{'active':group1?.isOpen}" >
 <div accordion-heading > Div 1</div>
```

and my css

```
.active[accordion-group] .panel-heading{
  background-color: black;
}
```

but it didn't work. i referred the angularJS answer mentioned in the post [Bootstrap 3 accordion styling on open/closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592441/bootstrap-3-accordion-styling-on-open-closed). can someone help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

just removed [accordion-group] and it worked perfectly.

```
.active .panel-heading{
  background-color: black;
}
```